# Can I define/link types to a class in typescript?

Tags: typescript

In typescript, is it possible to have "static type fields" in classes ? I know the following is invalid, but just to give you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
class Collection<Item> {
  items: [Item];
  constructor() { this.items = [] }
  type ItemType = Item; // invalid
}
function for_each<Container>(
  container: Container,
  f: (val:Container.ItemType) => any // invalid
)
  { /* ... */ }
var strings = new Collection<string>();
var int_processor = function (val: number) {}
for_each(strings, int_processor); // I'd like an error here
```

I'm new to typescript and I can't find if there exist a syntax to do this kind of things (kind of like typedefs inside classes in C++). Hopefully it would allow to get an error on the last line, so that I can catch at compile time that I can't run `int_processor` on `strings`.

Is it possible at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer original question - you can't define type alias inside a class. [Here's](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7061) relevant suggestion, which is not likely to be implemented.

---

But it seems what you're really looking for is how to extract generic type parameter.
You can use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) for this:

```
class Collection<Item> {
    items: Item[];
    constructor() { this.items = [] }
}

type GetItemType<T> = T extends Collection<infer ItemType> ? ItemType : never;

declare function for_each<Container>(
    container: Container,
    f: (val: GetItemType<Container>) => any
): void;

const strings = new Collection<string>();
const int_processor = function (val: number) { }
for_each(strings, int_processor); // Error: 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=15&ssc=88&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2IQFNgBcCW8B2AeAkmsgLYB80A3gLABQ090GRxEAXNISQNoC6A3LQbRgOCGgBOAV3TxxACgCUlaGgAWGCADomJGAF5ovaAF9apmrTQBPAA7JoAcWRpOxACq3kuN%20QNvoyAAeRNgAJjAISKiYOLgY2ABmyOIczB525AD8qSTp9uzYyABuyQIWNKGo4OL2CZLY6FjY0AmyAPrIYMCquAjYaGDxyaRyggwi-YOF4ux9A0PiADRj9AnsckVgIOxOLmmevTjz06RKeuRg2Fa0CuxF8BihZbQTYtBi4vEA5vrQhQDucEQKEasQ%203xGCjKrzQjH6bRs4ngwGQUFk0AMdQaMWaGy2BUkxAARsklBQTLRWuIOl1VHJwdgfos4WgEUiUWjxFDoAB6HnQACi4iRM2gAHIGV8xYwYNh4LDIBAMF9sGAiSgVPAVJ5xdhCSTxGKgA)

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I can work with that, but can you confirm if there exist a syntax for defining types within classes or not ?

Comment: No, you can't define type aliases within a class https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7061

Answer (score 1):

You can add [static properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#static-properties).
Here is your example adapted:

```
class Collection<Item> {
  items: [Item];
  static ItemType = {}; // your new ItemType here
  constructor() { this.items = [] }
}
function for_each<Container>(
  container: Container,
  f: (val:Container.ItemType) => any // invalid
)
  { /* ... */ }
var strings = new Collection<string>();
var int_processor = function (val: number) {}
for_each(strings, int_processor); // I'd like an error here
```

Comment: You're using value (static property) at type position - this won't compile

Comment: I don't understand your answer. ItemType is a static property of type `object` and value `{}` how is it related to the type `Item` ?